# Off-canvas menu foundation 6 in-canvas

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation-6, off-canvas-menu

I find myself confronted with a rather particular problem with the off-canvas menu of the foundation 6. Indeed, it is possible to make it in-canvas in the case where we pass on medium screens. Unfortunately, the in-canvas system is indeed overlap and I wish to put it in push when it is on small screens.

Is it possible ?

For the example shown here is the [link](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/off-canvas.html#in-canvas-to-off-canvas):

Sorry to ask directly on stackoverflow, but I can not ask my question on the forum of the foundation, my posts are not published and I still have no news of zurb support on this subject.